# hyperbolic triangles angle sum

Tags: geometry

In the accompanying figure M and N are the respective (hyperbolic) midpoints of AB and AC. $\phi$ and $\theta$ are indicated angle measures. Determine, with proof, which of the following is true: (1) $\phi$ =$\theta$ (2)$\theta$<$\phi$ (3) $\theta$> $\phi$.

[image]

If I could get a small hint that be great. I just don't see if I have to use angle defect and/or what other lines I need to draw in. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use angle defect. Indeed, think about what happens to $\theta$ as $M$ moves along $\overline{AB}$ to $M$.

Comment: You're over-complicating with quadrilaterals. What do you know about area($\triangle AMN$) compared to area($\triangle ABC$)?

Comment: its 1/2 of tiangle ABC

Comment: I certainly don't know that, but it definitely is less! So ... ?

Comment: I know im over complicating but I just am not seeing it.

Comment: how about drawing in line segment NB and then using defect? I think it might work.

Comment: If the area is less, what does that say about the angle defect?

Comment: Well that would mean the defect of the larger triangle is bigger than the smaller triangle defect.. But that would mean the internal angle sum of the small triangle is larger then that of the larger triangle.

Comment: Then the base angles of the smaller triangles sum are larger then the base angle sum of the larger triangle. But now proving which base angle of the smaller triangle is larger than which of the ones in the bigger triangle.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I seem to have been assuming the triangle was isosceles.

Answer (score 0):

Oh just connect BN. [image]

By exterior angle inequality from absolute geometry we know that $\theta>\angle MBN > \phi$.
Thus $\theta>\phi$. Answer is C.